# Should I also assure undefined in a jQuery plugin closure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I often see this described as the way to assure a safe environment for a jQuery plugin:

```
(function($){
  $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
    ...
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Wouldn't it be better to also safeguard undefined, like so:

```
(function($, undefined){
  $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
    ...
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Or does it not matter? and if so, why?

Comment: What do you mean by "safeguard undefined"?

Comment: Is it even possible to redefine undefined?

Comment: @JohnD: Yes it is. `undefined` is actually a property of the global object (i.e. `window.undefined`) (which has the *value* `undefined` by default).

Comment: @JohnD Yes.  According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined): "undefined is a property of the global object, i.e. it is a variable in global scope."

Comment: @FelixKling Interesting.

Comment: I think the reason Jquery plugins are written in closures is to prevent their variables from becoming global. It's to safeguard the plugin's variables, not the browser's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably not necessary. If you test whether a variable is `undefined`, you should prefer using

```
typeof variable === 'undefined'
```

anyway.

"Safeguarding" jQuery on the other hand is something you definitely should do, otherwise your plugin will not work if jQuery is used in `noConflict` mode.